# How can I fix my mistake about uploading files with PHP?

Tags: php, file-upload

During my experiments with |W 3 s c h o o l s| source code, I encountered the following problem:
My html and php codes are as below.

```html
# upload.html

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Upload File</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Select image to upload:
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```php
# upload.php

<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
  if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
  } else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }
}

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
  echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
  echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
  echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
  echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". htmlspecialchars( basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])). " has been uploaded.";
  } else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
  }
}
?>
```

The following displays are the file directories view, the view on the server and the error message:

[image: localhost directory]
[image: localhost html view]
[image: error output view on localhost]

Thanks in advance.

I've been working on a simple file upload with PHP. It accepts the file if it meets the specified conditions, but I'm wondering why it's returning an error message and why it's not uploading successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems the **uploads** directory is missing, create it then retry

script is trying to move the file to the uploads directory, but the directory does not exists.

Comment: ... `if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) { ... }` 

I understand that there is a problem with this line, but I don't understand what is wrong in the syntax. what do you mean by **uploads directory**?

Comment: trying to move the file to uploads directory. check the $target_dir variable.  ensure that the folder is created on the server.

Comment: Also (on a linux server) you may need to alter the ownership and / or the permissions of the uploads directory. For example on a debian based distro you can run `chown www-data:www-data uploads` www-data is the user name that Apache uses on a debian based system.

Comment: @guu876 thank u, As you said: creating an "uploads" folder in the same directory on the server solved the whole error. is there anything I can do for you? i will report it as solved. thanks.

Comment: @user3425506 thanks, You raise an important issue. I will look into it.

Comment: @kalawaja If it is working for you then probably there is no need at the moment but sometimes ownership and permission of files and directories is important (not just for file uploads of course)...

Comment: @user3425506 can it also pose a danger for attempts such as file bomber? after all, if you do not have enough space, can it be damaged by sending multiple files (I am ignorant about this)

Comment: @kalawaja I have not heard of file bomber but if you have a file upload input someone could use it to put a lot of and / or very large files on your server so you need to look into ways of preventing that. Also when you change file permissions and ownership there may be other security issues so that needs research as well. I am definitely not an expert!

Comment: @user3425506, you can put a limit to the filesize being uploaded, via speicifying in the php.ini file via tinkering with the upload_max_filesize and post_max_size settings

Comment: `if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) { ... }` ... apart from the precautions in [php . ini] are also important. good information. thanks to both of you. it was very useful for me.